# Linked list of objects

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I currently have a linked list class that can create Node objects that can store integer values. I want to modify my List class so that the nodes created will be able to reference pointers to objects from a different class rather than simple integer values. How would I go about declaring a pointer to an object that is being created in a different class.

This linked list class can create node objects that contain int values?

How do I get my linked list class to be able to store pointers to objects?

```
#ifndef LINK_H 
#define LINK_H

class List{
  private:
    typedef struct Node{
      int m_data;
      Node *next;
    }* node_ptr;

    node_ptr cur;
    node_ptr temp; 
    node_ptr head;

  public:
    List();
    void add_node(int);
    void del_node(int);
    void print();
};
#endif
```

This is the food class. I am trying to get my linked list to store pointers to objects that have been created from this class.

```
#ifndef FOOD_H
#define FOOD_H
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Food{

  private:

    string m_name;
    bool m_meat;
    int m_price;
    int m_calories;


  public:


    Food();
    Food(string , bool, int , int ); 
    bool is_meat(bool );
    void print(ostream &os);

};

#endif
```

Comment: The answer is simple: change it so that it does. Instead of an `int`, it's a pointer. What's so hard about that?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to do this change:

```
class List{
  private:
    typedef struct Node{
      Food* m_data;
      Node *next;
    }* node_ptr;

    node_ptr cur;
    node_ptr temp; 
    node_ptr head;

  public:
    List();
    void add_node(Food*);
    void del_node(Food*);
    void print();
};
```

This should work - you have to include the header, where the Food class is declared, or do a forward declaration of the Food class.

This code can be tweaked, to get better performance, be more flexible or safe. This is using more C++ features.
But consider doing this:

Don't use `using namespace std;` or any other namespace name in a header file. This will 'include' this namespace in every file you will include the header. This is bad, because you it pollutes the global namespace. So if you define a function `int cout () {}` there will be a clash with std::cout. This is a trivial case - but in bigger projects this is really important.